# How do I set an Angular 2 & webpack project to retrieve images from a context path?

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Using the Angular 2 Webpack starter here: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

I want to access the app at `http://localhost:3000/contextPath`, not `http://localhost:3000`

I have added the publicPath setting under output in webpack.dev.js:

```
  output: {
    publicPath: '/contextPath',
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
    library: 'ac_[name]',
    libraryTarget: 'var',
  },
```

And set the baseUrl in webpack.common.js:

```
const METADATA = {
  title: 'Angular2 Webpack Starter by @gdi2290 from @AngularClass',
  baseUrl: '/contextPath',
  isDevServer: helpers.isWebpackDevServer()
};
```

After running `webpack-dev-server` I am able to access the app at `http://localhost:3000/contextPath#/home`, the .js files are served correctly using the context path, like `http://localhost:3000/contextPath/polyfills.bundle.js`, but the angular shield image is broken and the page is trying to retrieve it from `http://localhost:3000/assets/img/angularclass-avatar.png`.

**How should I get the application to use the correct url for the image (including the context path), which is `http://localhost:3000/contextPath/assets/img/angularclass-avatar.png` ?**

App running at context path with broken image link:

[image: Running app with broken image link.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `baseUrl` and `publicPath` in my webpack config files needed to include a slash on the end. Setting them to `'/contextPath/'` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are wanting to set the `publicPath` property. Try setting:

`output.publicPath: '/contextPath'`.

Comment: I believe that has already been set in webpack.dev.js, but maybe that's not the right place? It seems to be affecting other content like the .js files, but not the shield image.

Comment: Do you only want it to affect your images path?

Comment: No, I want everything served from the context path, so the js files are fine. Although I set publicPath the image does not use it, which seems strange to me since the other assets do.